# WebDriver throws timeout error when trying to access Url property

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, .net-core, google-chrome-headless

I click on button which downloads PDF file from server and opens it in new tab. After click i wait when the tab will be opened:

```
    TimeSpan timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
    WebDriverWait waiter = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeSpan);
    waiter.Until(drv => drv.WindowHandles.Count == 2);
```

When this PDF file is opened i switch to new tab:

```
    string handle = drv.WindowHandles.Last();
    drv.SwitchTo().Window(handle);
```

Then i try to access Url property on web driver:

```
    TimeSpan timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
    WebDriverWait waiter = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeSpan);
    waiter.Until(driver => driver.Url.StartsWith("blob:"));
```

But i get this error:

***The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:44829/session/fc28864b05b7a2b3ad16fd69e29fb48d/url timed out after 60 seconds.***

This issue appears only in Headless mode on linux machine:

```
    public static IWebDriver Create()
    {
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

        options.AddArgument("headless");
        options.AddArgument("no-sandbox");
        options.AddArgument("window-size=1920x1080");

        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

        return driver;
    }
```

But there are no problems in simple chrome mode on Windows:

```
    public static IWebDriver Create()
    {
        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

        return driver;
    }
```

This issue appears when trying to search elements too.

Comment: I think this issue could be linked to your problem : https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/494